# Error 404 archivo o directorio no encontrado

Tags: windows, webservice, rest

Hola tengo una `api RestFull` alojada en `WINDOWS SERVER 2012` pero cuando trato de acceder a la información sucede el error 404 Ejemplo

> ip Domain/api/v1/ruta/trayecto/1

Para quienes conocen como funciona los `Servicios Web RESTful` saben que la información es dada a través de controladores en este caso es **RUTA** para lo cual no existe una carpeta.

Como puedo configurar el servidor para que permita consultar el `Servicio Web RESTful`

Comment: estas seguro que armas la ruta del webapi de forma correcta? es el unico servicio que expones? o sea falla este o todos los que tienes. Defines el verbo http de forma correcta, o sea es un servicio GET o POST

Comment: Todos fallan en un servidor que tengo Local en xammp todo funciona perfecto pero al migrar el proyecto a windows server no funciona

Comment: estas seguro que configuras el IIS de forma correcta? en que tecnologia estan estos servicios ?

Comment: Los servicios esta desarrollados en PHP, si abro un sitio el me abrira normal loq ue me hace pensar que PHP esta bien y el ISS esta publico para ser consultado desde otras maquinas

Comment: Pensaría que son permisos de Windows sobre esa carpeta. O sobre el archivo que estas intentando acceder. Comprueba también la configuración del apache.

Comment: Acabo de mirar y creo que tiene que ver con el htacces ya que al ser un server windows necesito es un web.config

Comment: Pero el web.config es de asp.net no de php, no configuras el servidor para que conozca como procesar php https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh994592(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Tienes razon pero el php ya esta configurado de manera correcta

Comment: Revisa con qué puertos está configurado tu API en tu server